# Switching processes for same variable(Geniouses)

Tags: python

Hello trying to learn python I wonder is there a shorter way of writting it?I am doing a shopping game all the name are numbers.

```
if a > b:
  cat=dad+elephant
  fat=girl+hat
  ice=jam-elephant
  jelly=lion-hat

  if money <= 0:
    money=0

  if credit <= 0:
    credit=0

else:
  cat=dad-elephant
  fat=girl-hat
  ice=jam+elephant
  jelly=lion+hat

  if money <= 0:
    money=0

  if credit <= 0:
    credit=0
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, but questions like these aren't what the site is used for. You're code is working fine, asking if it could be written shorter is more for Programmers Stack Exchange.

Comment: Where should I go?What should I do lost and confuse!How do I go programers?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

```
sign = 1 if a > b else -1

cat = dad + sign * elephant
fat = girl + sign * hat
ice = jam - sign * elephant
jelly = lion - sign * hat

if money < 0:
    money = 0

if credit < 0:
    credit = 0
```

Explanation:

- The first line uses the [trinary operator in Python](http://docs.python.org/3.3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator), which assigns the value of `1` to the variable `sign` if `a > b` and `-1` otherwise.
- If it's not true that `a > b` then in each of the four assignments (`cat = ...` through `jelly = ...`) the sign of the second term on the right side is flipped due to multiplication by `-1`, so addition becomes subtraction and vice versa.
- You don't need to check if `money` and `credit` are negative separately for each case.

Answer (score 0):

```
swapsign = 2*(a>b)-1
cat   = dad  + swapsign * elephant
fat   = girl + swapsign * hat
ice   = jam  - swapsign * elephant
jelly = lion - swapsign * hat

money  = max(money,  0)
credit = max(credit, 0)
```

Comment: Chears:))))))))))))))))))))) To low reputation to uprove but soon will

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import add, sub

op = add if a > b else sub

cat   = op(dad, elephant)
fat   = op(girl, hat)
ice   = op(jam, -elephant)
jelly = op(lion, -hat)

money  = max(0, money)
credit = max(0, credit)
```